# Multiple arguments for tprint from art

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I am using `tprint` from `art` (code is shown below), and I want to make it look coloured, using `colorama`, but when I run the code, I get white instead of magenta, but a few wacky letters infront of it.

Input:

[image: my input]

Output:
[image: my output]

How do I fix this? (Art can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/art/).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no problem using text2art instead of tprint, the following code should do the job.

```
from art import *
from colorama import Fore

art = text2art("meh")
print(Fore.MAGENTA + art)
```